# C# System.Timers creating massive thread count - Can I abort the thread to fix the issue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm currently writing something in C# (which I've never really used before) that involves a single timer `System.Timers.Timer`  firing 7 queries run against an Oracle Database. It's designed to be running continuously and indefinitely on a server.

When looking at the process running in the Windows Resource Monitor, the thread count was just increasing. At an interval of 10 seconds, it had reached 230 threads in under an hour. I guess that every time the timer fires, it creates a new thread but I can't really work out what's wrong. I assumed that I wouldn't have to explicitly end the thread after the task had been completed.

However, when I added a `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()`after the last query had finished doing work, the thread count stays at 15. Also, memory usage is quite a lot better too.

Is aborting the thread the right thing to do? It feels very wrong but it has fixed the problem.

Comment: You should not use `Abort`, and you should show us the code creating the timer and the code for when the timer elapses.

Comment: You should try and code it to let the thread terminate naturally after completing its work.

Comment: You should stop the timer while work is in progress and resume when it is done.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: That entirely depends on the requirements. Sometimes that is a good thing to do. Other times it is not.

Comment: @JohnWillemse is right, stop the timer while you perform work, that way your threads aren't competing against each other. in your handler you simply stop the timer at the start of the function, and restart it when you leave the function. Also, if you have objects which are not managed, and require disposal (your oracle db connection for instance), then the thread will be hung open and never terminate because there are still objects that belong to it in memory, this is also a huge memory leak btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Thread.Abort() is of course not a proper fix, just a band-aid that hides the true problem. You must find out why these threads don't stop running by themselves.

Do so by using the debugger. Debug + Windows + Threads show these threads. Select one that looks like a timer callback thread and look at its call stack so see where it got stuck. Best done by also enabling unmanaged debugging and enabling the Microsoft symbol server so you can also see it being stuck in code you didn't write.  The name of a DLL you find back in the call stack is usually a hint.

Answer (score -1):

See the remarks on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8.aspx

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

Basically this looks like your query does either not finish in the given time or it locks the thread on which it is running.